# Expansion of square root of (a-b)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

I am interested in expanding:

$$\sqrt{a-b}$$

Assuming $a>0$ and $b>0$, and that $a>b$.

When I write this in Wolfram alpha, the expansion is as follows:

$$\approx \sqrt{-b} +\frac{a}{2\sqrt{-b}}-\frac{a^2}{8(-b)^{3/2}}+...$$

Why do they write square roots of negative numbers?

Does anyone understand how Wolfram developed this Taylor expansion?

Thanks!

Comment: It's perfectly correct if $b < 0$.

Comment: Thanks.  I am interested in the case when both a and b are strictly greater than 0.

Comment: What value of $a$ do you want to expand the series about?  Right now this is (the correct) expansion for a Taylor series about $a = 0$.

Comment: What's the input that you asked from Wolfram alpha?

Comment: It looks like an expansion around $a=0$.  Weird!  Makes sense (?) only for $|a|\le |b|$.

Comment: @Andrei: input asked from Wolfram alpha: expand sqrt(a-b).

Comment: Let $x=b/a \in (0,1)$. Then expand $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{1-x}$. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+sqrt%281-x%29).

Comment: If you want an expansion, *you* need to decide: (a) in terms of which variable, and (b) around which point. You cannot just say "I want to expand $\sqrt{a-b}$". Here you would get a more sensible result if expanding in the powers of $b$ around $b=0$, but you can do other things. (E.g. in powers of $b-a$ around $b=a$.)

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha always assumes you are using imaginary numbers. So $\sqrt{-b}$ is nothing special for it.

Comment: @StinkingBishop:  Note, however, that the Taylor series of $f(a) = \sqrt{a-b}$ is not well-defined at $a = b$, since $f'(b)$ does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert True, that is why I did not include that as one of the possibilities above.

Comment: @statistics123 Wolfram expands on the first variable (in your case $a$), around the $0$. Note that your function at $a=0$ is $\sqrt{0-b}$. If $b>0$, this number is complex. If you don't allow complex numbers, than the Taylor expansion around $a_0=0$ does not make sense, since $f(a_0)$ is not defined.

Comment: as in comment by @lhf divide out by $\sqrt a$  and call $x = \frac{b}{a},$  then gp-pari says $\sqrt{1-x}$ expands ( they put fraction coefficients first, annoying)  1 - 1/2*x - 1/8*x^2 - 1/16*x^3 - 5/128*x^4 - 7/256*x^5 - 21/1024*x^6 - 33/2048*x^7 - 429/32768*x^8 - 715/65536*x^9 - 2431/262144*x^10 - 4199/524288*x^11 - 29393/4194304*x^12 - 52003/8388608*x^13 - 185725/33554432*x^14 - 334305/67108864*x^15 + O(x^16)

Comment: @StinkingBishop, how do I decide which point I want the Taylor series around?

Comment: @statistics123 It is the point around which you want to approximate your function by a polynomial/partial sum of the series.